# declaring and using variables in a trigger

Tags: mysql

I am declaring some variables in my mysql trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER lestrigger
    AFTER INSERT ON examinations
   FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE the_last_inserted_id INT ;
    DECLARE the_class_id INT;
    DECLARE the_year_id INT;

    SET the_last_inserted_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SET the_class_id = select examination_class_id from examinations where examination_id = the_last_inserted_id;
    SET the_year_id = select examination_class_year_id from examinations where examination_id = the_last_inserted_id;

    insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id) select cs_id from class_students where cs_class_id = the_class_id AND cs_year_id = the_year_id,the_last_inserted_id;

END
  //
DELIMITER ;
```

but i keep getting this error

> /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'select examination_class_id from examinations
>   where examination_id = the_last_in' at line 10 */

Is the way i am using my variables syntactically right?.

Comment: Try adding parentheses around the select queries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797424/selecting-values-to-a-variable-inside-mysql-triggers

Answer (score 0):

Use `INTO` keyword http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

```
select examination_class_id into the_class_id from examinations where examination_id = the_last_inserted_id;
select examination_class_year_id into the_year_id from examinations where examination_id = the_last_inserted_id;
```

Comment: That worked too,but how about this `insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id) (select cs_id from class_students where cs_class_id = the_class_id AND cs_year_id = the_year_id),the_last_inserted_id);` .I am trying to insert into an extra column.Do i surround the select statement as well with `(` and `)`?.

Comment: Not sure about the parenthesis, but it could not badly impact the query. So add it if you are not sure. Otherwise, your query is correct, except the missing keyword `VALUES` before data.